# Passing data PHP(client-side) to C#(server-side)

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html, opencv

I want to develop a web based face recognition API. The system that will process face recognition is in c# application(opencv). My problem is how to pass data from php to c#? I already tested it by using fleck websocket, it could use the webcam of website(client) and send the image byte via websocket to c# opencv application(server) and return the processed output again to the website. see http://www.smartjava.org/content/face-detection-using-html5-javascript-webrtc-websockets-jetty-and-javacvopencv for similar result. However I am looking for an alternative aside from websocket, because I want to make my own API like rekognition and I don't know where to start.

Hoping for help :)

Comment: php is server side and C# application is client side

Comment: I mean the website :) sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You use WCF to expose a SOAP interface for your C# service, and then consume it from PHP like any other SOAP service. You can also expose a [RESTful interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) with WCF.